# How does react-native scripts work?

Tags: react-native

When I run `react-native run-android` in a project. what actually happens. Where can I read the actual script? How can I change it's behavior ?
In particular I am interested in this project: [Status React project](https://github.com/status-im/status-react) I just don't know where to start searching. How can I change flow of `react-native run-android`  . I wonder: does it call any callbacks to redefine in my project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The functionality for `react-native`'s `run-android` subroutine is held within the [`react-native/local-cli/runAndroid/runAndroid.js`](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/d846696f49fc0b4eb3d90d5788b5521aa4ec643b/local-cli/runAndroid/runAndroid.js) file. You can change it's behavior by modifying this file.

Comment: I wonder: does it call any callbacks to redefine in my project instead of in the plugin itself.